# Html header element appears in body when using <DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, doctype

I'm a beginner in web programming and I found out that when I have my `header.php` without the `<DOCTYPE html>` declaration in the beginning the html structure looks right as you can see [here](http://php4you.de/upload/admin/tutorials/header_footer_1/index.php) in a short example.

But when I modify the `header.php` and use the `<DOCTYPE html>`, the html structure changes to:

```
<html>
    <head></head> <!-- empty head -->
    <body>
        <doctype html>
            <title>Title</title>
            "


            context

             "
        </doctype>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is that?

#### Edit: This question is just the result of a basic typo mistake.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> Also, it should be before the opening <html> tag. As per answer below

Comment: I think you should get an ***HTML 101*** course, IMHO. Your syntax is way off and what do the other tags besides "html" have to do with the question? There's no php to support the question, just *"But when I modify the header.php"*.

Comment: Please see [HTML Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/)

Comment: *"Does this mean I shouldn't use anymore?"* - It means that your html markup is invalid. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML and https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110525/ and http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/ to name a few of *many!*

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I didn't read through that properly and just adjusted the initial doctype.

Correction:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title>Title</title>
     </head>
     <body>


     </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Please also paste your code [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: title not allowed as child of element body